# VB.NET Insert DatagridView to existing Word Document

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, datagridview

Okay, I've been trying to work out a problem I've had for the past few weeks and scouring through StachOverflow helped a little but not a great amount for it to actually work.

I have a document called template.docx
Created this using online sources.

My Imports:

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Imports System.IO
```

ReplaceWith in word.

```
Public Sub InsertTextFieldsToTemplate(TemplateLoc As String, InvoiceLoc As String)

        Dim oWord As New Word.Application
        oWord.Visible = False

        'Open an existing document.  
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oWord.Documents.Open(TemplateLoc)
        oDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument

        'TR (Item to Replace) RW (Replace Item With)
        Dim TR(5) As String
        Dim RW(5) As String

        TR(0) = "REF#BUSINESSNAME"
        TR(1) = "REF#CUSTNAME"
        TR(2) = "REF#CUSTADDRESS"
        RW(0) = txt_businessname.Text
        RW(1) = txt_customer_name.Text
        RW(2) = txt_customer_address.Text
        
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            'Find and replace some text  
            oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=TR(i), ReplaceWith:=RW(i), Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
        Next

        'Save and close the document  
        oDoc.SaveAs(InvoiceLoc)
        oDoc.Close()
        oDoc = Nothing
        oWord.Quit()
        oWord = Nothing
```

The above works fine. Could do with streamlining but it works.

In that same document, I want to add values from a datagrid. [DGV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s20W.jpg)

As you can see, i add to this DGV manually with textboxes. I want these values entered into this DGV to be inserted into the new document that the previous sub created as the function ReplaceWith won't work with the datagrid (Or so im told)

```
Public Sub InsertDGVToCreatedDoc(NewInvoice)

       Dim oWord As New Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document
        oWord.Visible = True
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(NewInvoice, False, False)
        oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Rows.Add()

        For Each row In grid_main.Rows
            For Each column In grid_main.Columns
                oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(row, column).Range.Text = row & column
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

At this moment I get the error "conversion from type DataGridViewRow to type Integer is not valid, but I have a feeling I'm doing this wrong and as more time goes on, I'm making more mistakes with it.

**FYI:** I've also tried saving a differant method, I can save the DGV to CSV without any issues, but I can't import the CSV to the same document. (too many errors to list, so i started again)

I see this: [datagridview to word with C# in existing word file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943865/datagridview-to-word-with-c-sharp-in-existing-word-file)

but I have no idea how to do anything with C# or even convert this to VB.NET

I'm struggling a little and pulling my hair out. Can anyone help? or at least point me to a resource that a n00b can understand. Thank you.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71649599/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394482/10024425

Comment: The first link is where i got the ReplaceWith to work. Great article. The second one is in C# and while some of it looks familer I have no idea what I'm doing with that.

Comment: While the OP may be tagged as C#, the referenced post (ie: answer)  is written in VB.NET.

Comment: I see, my apologies, I've looked through that but this doesn't help me. It creates a new word document from the datagrid but not insert into existing. I will have a look through it and try to learn how it creates it. Might be able to adapt it myself within a week or two.

Comment: The issue is really oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell()  takes integer arguments, but you are passing it in a row and column objects.  So there are two options I see 1) Use a standard for loop rather than a For Each (where i = row index, j = column index for example) or 2) Get the index of the row/columns your dealing with to pass the Cells() method

Comment: omg, this is working. Thank you so much.
It has highlighted a second problem tho. Its inserting the data fine, just to the wrong table in the template. do I need to give a name or ID to the table i want?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that this is how to use [comment @replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). For example, Hursey didn't receive an inbox notification of your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For row As Integer = 1 to grid_main.Rows.Count
        For column As Integer = 1 to grid_main.Columns
            oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(row, column).Range.Text = grid_main.Rows(row-1).Cells(column-1).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Next
```

I *think* MS Word uses 1-based arrays, which is why we subtract 1 from row and column when pulling data out of grid_main (e.g. `grid_main.Rows(row-1).Cells(column-1).Value`)

Otherwise you can start counting from 0 instead of 1 in the loops.